# Tag rows based on the conditions on 2 columns

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr

I have a data like below

```
    concat         Type   ddate      TTIME
1348 - 2019-06-10   B   6/10/2019   12:34:03
1348 - 2019-06-10   A   6/10/2019   12:38:02
1348 - 2019-06-10   B   6/10/2019   13:37:15
1348 - 2019-06-11   A   6/11/2019   14:35:20
1348 - 2019-06-11   B   6/11/2019   18:01:01
1348 - 2019-06-11   A   6/11/2019   18:02:42
1348 - 2019-06-11   B   6/11/2019   19:59:34
```

I am trying to add a tag where for concat group, if the minimum time = Type A and Maximum of Time = Type B then needs to add include for all the line items of concat group. Else needs to mark as exclude for all the line items of the particular concat group like below:

```
       concat      Type   ddate       TTIME    Category
1348 - 2019-06-10   B   6/10/2019   12:34:03    Exclude
1348 - 2019-06-10   A   6/10/2019   12:38:02    Exclude
1348 - 2019-06-10   B   6/10/2019   13:37:15    Exclude
1348 - 2019-06-11   A   6/11/2019   14:35:20    Include
1348 - 2019-06-11   B   6/11/2019   18:01:01    Include
1348 - 2019-06-11   A   6/11/2019   18:02:42    Include
1348 - 2019-06-11   B   6/11/2019   19:59:34    Include
```

I tried like below but not able to generate the desired output

```
df1 = df1 %>% 
arrange(concat, time) %>% 
group_by(concat) %>% 
mutate(
 Category = ifelse((TTIME == min(TTIME) & Type =="A") & (TTIME == max(TTIME) & Type =="B"),"Include","Exclude"))
```

Comment: Try using the or operator ( | ) in your code between your two tests. You have & (and)  which would mean you wouldn't have any true values (you can't have both Type == "B" and Type == "A")

Comment: But if I use or operator, if any of the condition satisfies I may get "Include". I.e. even when max(TTIME) == A, I will end up getting Include; For me, the minimum of TTIME should be A and Maximum of TTIME should be B (both the conditions needs to be satisfied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider separating these conditions to make this easier to work with.

To illustrate an example, you could recode rows where the `min` for `TTIME` is with `Type == "A"` (and similarly for `max` and `Type == "B"`).

Then, for a group to be included, the group must contain both "A" and "B".

Does this have the logic you were looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  arrange(concat, TTIME) %>% 
  group_by(concat) %>%
  mutate(match = case_when(
    TTIME == min(TTIME) & Type == "A" ~ "A",
    TTIME == max(TTIME) & Type == "B" ~ "B")) %>%
  mutate(Category = ifelse(all(c("A", "B") %in% match), "Include", "Exclude"))

# A tibble: 7 x 6
# Groups:   concat [2]
  concat          Type  ddate     TTIME               match Category
  <fct>           <fct> <fct>     <dttm>              <chr> <chr>   
1 1348-2019-06-10 B     6/10/2019 2019-10-30 12:34:03 NA    Exclude 
2 1348-2019-06-10 A     6/10/2019 2019-10-30 12:38:02 NA    Exclude 
3 1348-2019-06-10 B     6/10/2019 2019-10-30 13:37:15 B     Exclude 
4 1348-2019-06-11 A     6/11/2019 2019-10-30 14:35:20 A     Include 
5 1348-2019-06-11 B     6/11/2019 2019-10-30 18:01:01 NA    Include 
6 1348-2019-06-11 A     6/11/2019 2019-10-30 18:02:42 NA    Include 
7 1348-2019-06-11 B     6/11/2019 2019-10-30 19:59:34 B     Include
```

Comment: Thanks Ben; However I have done this by taking a long like split the data and merge back, this is really helpful as a learning for going forward.